# Obtain column values based on changes in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
dateColumnDF <- c("2022-04-12 00:02:57", "2022-04-12 00:02:58", "2022-04-12 00:02:59", "2022-04-12 00:03:00", "2022-04-12 00:03:02")
ValueColumnDf <- c("50","465","788","99","25")
Var1Df <- c("0", "0", "0","0","0")
Var2Df <- c("0", "0", "1","1","0")
Var3Df <- c("0","1","0","1","0")
df <- data.frame(dateColumnDF, ValueColumnDf,Var1Df,Var2Df,Var3Df)
colnames(df) <- c("timestamp","Value","Var1","Var2","Var3")
```

And I want to obtain a dataframe that reflects the way the Varx values have been changing, from one value to another (mainly from 0 to 1 and back), like this:

```
firstColumn <- c("Var2", "Var2", "Var3", "Var3", "Var3","Var3")
secondColumn <- c("1", "0", "1","0","1","0")
thirdColumn <- c("2022-04-12 00:02:59", "2022-04-12 00:03:02", "2022-04-12 00:02:58","  
2022-04-12 00:02:59","2022-04-12 00:03:00","2022-04-12 00:03:02")
fourthColum <- c("788","25","465","788","99","25")
df2 <- data.frame(firstColumn,secondColumn,thirdColumn,fourthColum)
colnames(df2) <- c("Var","flagChangedTo","timestamp","Value")
```

I have found that to see the changes in each row I need to to do (using dplyr):

```
which(df$value!= dplyr::lag(df$value))
```

And that I would need to put this inside a loop of the columns of interest, something like this:

```
for(i in 3:ncol(df)) {
  x <- which(df[,i]!= dplyr::lag(df[,i]))
}
```

After I obtain the places where it changes how can I generate the desired matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyr::pivot_longer` (you were already using `dplyr`), you can turn the table into long form.

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, starts_with("Var"), names_to = "Var", values_to = "flagChangedTo")
```

This gives

```
   timestamp           Value Var   flagChangedTo
   <fct>               <fct> <chr> <fct>        
 1 2022-04-12 00:02:57 50    Var1  0            
 2 2022-04-12 00:02:57 50    Var2  0            
 3 2022-04-12 00:02:57 50    Var3  0            
 4 2022-04-12 00:02:58 465   Var1  0            
 5 2022-04-12 00:02:58 465   Var2  0            
...
```

After that, we can group by `Var` and use `filter` to keep only the rows in which the `flagChangedTo` value of the previous row is not equal to the current row, using `dplyr::lag` (like you already correctly suggested).

Put together, and using the magrittr pipe (`%>%`):

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Var"), names_to = "Var", values_to = "flagChangedTo") %>% 
  group_by(Var) %>% 
  arrange(timestamp) %>% 
  filter(flagChangedTo != lag(flagChangedTo)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(Var, timestamp)
```

Which gives

```
  timestamp           Value Var   flagChangedTo
  <fct>               <fct> <chr> <fct>        
1 2022-04-12 00:02:59 788   Var2  1            
2 2022-04-12 00:03:02 25    Var2  0            
3 2022-04-12 00:02:58 465   Var3  1            
4 2022-04-12 00:02:59 788   Var3  0            
5 2022-04-12 00:03:00 99    Var3  1            
6 2022-04-12 00:03:02 25    Var3  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Bas response:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(cols=Var1:Var3) %>% 
    arrange(name, timestamp) %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    filter(value!=lag(value)) %>% 
    select(Var=name, flagChangedTo=value,timestamp,Value)
```

Output:

```
  Var   flagChangedTo timestamp           Value
  <chr> <chr>         <chr>               <chr>
1 Var2  1             2022-04-12 00:02:59 788  
2 Var2  0             2022-04-12 00:03:02 25   
3 Var3  1             2022-04-12 00:02:58 465  
4 Var3  0             2022-04-12 00:02:59 788  
5 Var3  1             2022-04-12 00:03:00 99   
6 Var3  0             2022-04-12 00:03:02 25
```